# Why is VBS If Then Label Expression not working?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, vbscript

I am trying to label a field based on other field.

```vbs
For 
[TYPE] = "PRIMARY", the [LABEL] is having this structure: "TAN80901B"
For 
[TYPE] = "SECONDARY", the [LABEL] is like this: "TAN80901C/D20b"
```

I want the `[LABEL]` to return "`B`" if "`PRIMARY`" and "`D20`" if "`SECONDARY`"

To delete from the right and left, I can use : "`left(right( [LABEL], 5), 2)`"

Any help with this expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i follow you correctly, you can do this in vbs without using the left/right

```vbs
Dim Result
if [TYPE] = "PRIMARY" 
   then Result = "B"
elseif [TYPE] = "SECONDARY" 
   then Result = "D20"
End If
```

[LABEL] = Result

---

with the new information (and how i understand your question) i think this will work (I am not at the office nor do I have Arc handy to test) :

```vbs
Dim Result
    if [TYPE] = "PRIMARY" 
       then Result = Right([LABEL],1)
    elseif [TYPE] = "SECONDARY" 
       then Result = Right([LABEL],3)
    End If
```

[LABEL] = Result

Comment: Thanks! I need left/right because [LABEL] is having unique characters: TAN80901A, TAN80901B, TAN80901C, TAN80901C/D05b, TAN80901C/D10b, TAN80901C/D20b...

Comment: I dont follow,  could you give a little bit better pseudocode/logic I bet I can figure it out though.  Or maybe you can show a screenshot of your table and exactly what you are doing.

Comment: I am not sure if I can paste a image here.

Comment: However, the field "TYPE" has 2 values: PRIMARY and SECONDARY and the field "LABEL" has 3 unique values for PRIMARY and hundred of values when SECONDARY:   TAN80901A, TAN80901B and TAN80901C (for TYPE = PRIMARY) and TAN80901C/D05b, TAN80901C/D10b, TAN80901C/D20b, TAN80901C/D19b...etc (for TYPE = SECONDARY). I need to extract "A", "B" and "C", if TYPE is PRIMARY (ex: TAN80901A) and D01-D20 if TYPE is SECONDARY (ex: TAN80901C/D20b).

Answer (score 2):

If you switch the parser to Python, and desired Secondary values are always the same length and position (e.g., Secondary is always the last 4 characters), you could do this:

```vbs
def FindLabel([PRIMARY], [SECONDARY]):
    primType = [PRIMARY].upper()
    second = [SECONDARY].upper()
    if primType == 'PRIMARY':
        return second[-1]  # last character of SECONDARY
    elif primType == 'SECONDARY':
        return second[-4:-1]  # characters 4th from last to 2nd from last of SECONDARY
    else:
        pass # in case of Null/empty values
```